# Correctly escaping dash (-) in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query, which fails at the dash:

```sql
'create table 4$0_Anzahl_der_Anforderungen_des_V-NEF_2019 (Monat INTEGER, Eigenschaft_1 FLOAT, constraint pk_1 primary key(Monat));' }
```

With the following error:

```
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"4$0_Anzahl_der_Anforderungen_des_V-NEF"_2019 (Monat INTEGER, Eigenschaft_1 FLOA' at line 1
```

I already tried replacing the `-` with `\-`, but that didn't help. How do I replace it correctly?

Comment: Simple solution:  Give your table a simpler name, just consisting of letters, digits, and underscore.

Comment: The user should be allowed to keep their predefined names when entering data here, so this wasn't an option here.

Comment: @user3742929 Unless it is a kind of development tool, this should be solved in a different way.

Comment: I second @gordon_linoff comment. While technically you can use "special characters" in object names, it isn't a good idea. For starters you will always have to escape it everytime you reference it and even more annoyingly sooner or later you will come across a tool that doesn't and you want be able to access that object using that tool. Make life simple and pick a simple name if you can. As for the user, there has to be a point where they must follow some rules...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mysql For create valid object name including spaces,  reserved  word  or special char as dash,  minus or plus You need  backtics

```
 create table `4$0_Anzahl_der_Anforderungen_des_V-NEF_2019`
```