# Need help in deleting/drop my database in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database named as "sql-mystery". I'm unable to delete using -

```
DROP DATABASE sql-mystery;
```

I'm getting error like -

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sql-mystery' at line 1
```

What am I missing?.

Comment: Wrap your table name in backticks.

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481618/correctly-escaping-dash-in-mysql-query

Comment: I don't think thats a valid name for database. Still can you try with DROP DATABASE `sql-mystery';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using

```
    DROP DATABASE `sql-mystery`;
```

Answer (score 2):

try with  back-ticks for the Database name

```
DROP DATABASE `sql-mystery`
```